# Retriving data from table, where their are 3 table A,B,C . And refrence of Table C is in B, Table's B refrence is in A

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please tell me the sql query for following scenario,

- 3 table, Table A, Table B, Table C
- C refrence is present in Table B,
- B's refrence is present in table A.

And I want all the data from C where A=123, and B=212.

How can I get the data ? You can take any example and can explain it, Just that 3 table should have relation with each other( i.e it should have foriegn keys), And query should be using joins.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Use join. And tell exactly what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: I have been asked this question in an interview.
So please consider whatever table structure you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT c.*
FROM TableC c 
     INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.CID = c.ID 
     INNER JOIN TableA a ON a.BID = b.ID
WHERE   a.ID = 123
AND     b.ID = 212
```